# Delay Loaded DLL and Reg-Free COM

Tags: c#, com

I have isolated a COM object in a C# DLL. I have marked the COM reference as isolated. I see the manifest being generated. Loading the DLL using `Assembly.LoadFrom` and calling a class wrapping the COM call is throw an exception about the class no being registered.

If I do the same thing with an EXE the process behaves as expected. I can unregister the COM DLL, call the same method I'm trying to call in the managed DLL and it works successfully.

If I create an EXE, reference the said managed DLL, it also works. Is there any way to do this with Assembly.LoadFrom?

This code is really no more complicated than this:

```
public class SomeClass()
{
     public void CallCOM()
     {
          MyComObject obj = new MyComObject();
          obj.SomeCOMCall();
     }
}
```

Is it intended to work this way?

Comment: This is a heavy duty native Windows loader detail.  If it isn't involved in loading the DLL then it won't see the manifest.  Seeing this not being done at LoadFrom() isn't that unexpected.  Embed the manifest in the EXE instead.

Comment: I've found I can get this to work using CreateAtcCtx and ActivateAtcCtx. Seems like this could cause problems in the future though...